# Python Tkinter - Quit Button Not Working if Other Button Clicked First

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I would like my "Quit" button to close the window and end the program no matter when it is pressed. Right now it works if it is pressed first, but if the "Roll" button is pressed first then the "Quit" button doesn't close the window. I am a beginner programmer, so I'm sure there are unrelated issues with my code, but thanks in advance if you can help me out with this particular issue!

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import randint 

class Application(Frame):

def displayBoard(self): 
    self.canvas1 = Canvas(self, width=200, height=200)
    self.canvas1.pack()
    self.canvas2 = Canvas(self, width=200, height=200)
    self.canvas2.pack()

    self.roll_button = Button(self, text="Roll the Dice", command=self.roll)
    self.roll_button.pack()

    self.clear = Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.resetBoard)
    self.clear.pack()

    self.quit = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
    self.quit.pack()


def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    Pack.config(self)


def roll(self):
    die1 = faces[(randint(1,6)-1)]
    die2 = faces[(randint(1,6)-1)]
    self.resetBoard()
    self.canvas1.create_text(20, 30, anchor=W, text=die1)
    self.canvas1.pack()

    self.canvas2.create_text(20, 30, anchor=W, text=die2)
    self.canvas2.pack() 


def resetBoard(self):
    self.canvas1.destroy()
    self.canvas2.destroy()
    self.clear.destroy()
    self.roll_button.destroy()
    self.quit.destroy()
    self.displayBoard()

def quit(self):
    self.master.quit()
    self.master.destroy()

master = Tk()


    face1 = """\n
 __________
|                  |
|                  |
|        ( )       |
|                  |
|__________|
"""

face2 =  """\n
 __________
|                  |
|          ( )     |
|                  |
|    ( )           |
|__________|
"""
face3 = """ \n
 __________
|                  |
|            ( )   |
|       ( )        |
|   ( )            |
|__________|
"""


face4 = """\n 
 __________
|                  |
|    ( )   ( )     |
|                  |
|    ( )   ( )     |
|__________|
"""

face5 = """ \n
 __________
|                  |
|    ( )    ( )    |
|        ( )       |
|    ( )    ( )    |
|__________|
"""

face6 = """ \n
 __________
|                  |
|    ( )    ( )    |
|    ( )    ( )    |
|    ( )    ( )    |
|__________|
"""

faces = [face1, face2, face3, face4, face5, face6]

dicegame = Application()
dicegame.displayBoard()
dicegame.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try renaming your `quit()` function; when you try resetting the board, it may be picking up that `self.quit` is a `Button` and is calling the button as its action. Might be throwing an internal dead reference that just is silenced or something.

Comment: @Delioth: that's exactly what's happening. `self.quit` means different things at different times in this code.

Answer (score 0):

(For later programmers with this issue who stumble here)

The issue with this is you have the *function* `self.quit` and *also* a button `self.quit`. Python won't overload names - `self.quit` after initialization is a function, but after the first time you call `self.resetBoard`, the *button* is associated with `self.quit`- destroying your reference to the function.

The solution to this is to just rename one of them, and remember to avoid naming conflicts. Some pythonic ways include:

- Internal functions can be named with a leading underscore `self._quit()`
- Avoiding namespace clashes with builtins (quit() is builtin) is typically done with a trailing underscore `self.quit_()`
- More descriptive names for your button, i.e. `self.quit_button`; or for your function, i.e. `self.on_quit()`, `self.quit_app()`, `self.destroy()` (note that last one would NEED to call super().destroy() somewhere inside otherwise you'll break things)